# Hello, World! program for React Native throws "Could not parse the simulator list output" on Mac

Tags: react-native

I just started learning React Native and was trying to run my *Hello, World!* app using the steps given in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

I took the following steps

```
1. `brew install watchman`
2. `npm install -g react-native-cli`
3. `react-native init hello`
4. `cd hello`
5. `react-native run-ios`
```

Instead of launching the iOS app, I got the following error in the terminal:

```
Found Xcode project hello.xcodeproj
Usage: simctl list [devices|devicetypes|runtimes]
Could not parse the simulator list output
```

I also tried to run it using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode); however Xcode shows lot of compilation errors.

Following are details on my system

1. OS: [Mac OS v10.10.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite)
2. [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) version: 4.4.1
3. Xcode version: Version 6.3 (6D554n)

Following is a screenshot of errors shown in Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I realized that I was using a beta version of Xcode. Once I installed the latest version of Xcode then all errors were gone and the app were launched in the simulator.

Answer (score 30):

Error disappeared after I **launched Xcode** and allowed to install some updates.

Comment: I also had to close the current Simulator I had open for this latest build. If you kept it open and tried to run your app, it would just show a black screen.

Answer (score 16):

The problem was that I **updated Xcode** and never opened it after the update completed. After I opened Xcode it did **install components** then when I tried again it worked fine.

Comment: Nice duplicate.

Answer (score 13):

In my situation, I closed the current terminal and reopened it, then the error was gone.